# What do pixeltypes in PostGIS raster mean?

Tags: postgis, raster, postgis-2.0

I'm trying to build a raster in PostGIS from a vector layer and I was curious as to the meaning of pixeltypes in the raster geometry? How does it effect my raster?

Comment: Pixel types describe how many bits (bytes) and what range can be expected. Byte types can store integer values whereas float types can store floating point decimal values. It depends on how many values (and if the're integer or decimal) as to what pixel type you want.

Answer (score 3):

[This page](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_BandPixelType.html) lists the possible pixel type values that you can use for a raster band.

> 1. 1BB - 1-bit boolean (0 or 1)
> 2. 2BUI - 2-bit unsigned integer
> 3. 4BUI - 4-bit unsigned integer
> 4. 8BSI - 8-bit signed integer
> 5. 8BUI - 8-bit unsigned integer
> 6. 16BSI - 16-bit signed integer
> 7. 16BUI - 16-bit unsigned integer
> 8. 32BSI - 32-bit signed integer
> 9. 32BUI - 32-bit unsigned integer
> 10. 32BF - 32-bit float
> 11. 64BF - 64-bit float

The type you choose to use will depend on the phenomenon you're representing as a raster. For instance, if you just want a Boolean surface ("yes/no", "true/false",  "present/absent", "1/0", or "1/NULL"), then you'd most likely want a '1BB' pixel type. Choosing anything else will mean your raster will be larger than you need it to be (in terms of file size). Not choosing '1BB' in this example will also mean that cell values will be able to take values that they shouldn't be able to take (e.g. a value of 2.6 would be meaningless if you wanted a Boolean surface).

If your surface is categorical, you probably want one of the integer types. If you phenomenon is continuous, you almost certainly want a floating point value (the cell values can have decimal places).

The signed/unsigned distinction refers to whether your cell values can be positive or negative (signed), or only represented as positive values (values ≥ 0; unsigned).

The right choice depends on your phenomenon of interest, and then you want to pick the option that gives you an acceptable level of precision while keeping your file size down—although that may not be important if it is a one-off dataset.